# Using multiple small arrays in place of large one

Tags: c, arrays, struct

In a bid to increase parallelization of code, I'm trying to use a structure with 17 different sub-arrays, as opposed to a structure with one giant 17-dimensional array, by doing this:

```
int n_1[box1];
int n_2[box2];
int n_3[box3];
int n_4[box4];
int n_5[box5];
int n_6[box6];
int n_7[box7];
int n_8[box8];
int n_9[memvara];
int n_10[memvarb];
int n_11[memvarc];
int n_12[memvard];
int n_13[adirect];
int n_14[tdirect];
int n_15[fs];
int n_16[bs];
int n_17[outputnum];

// Set up a pointer-based structure
typedef struct calookup_b
{
    int *n_1;
    int *n_2;
    int *n_3;
    int *n_4;
    int *n_5;
    int *n_6;
    int *n_7;
    int *n_8;
    int *n_9;
    int *n_10;
    int *n_11;
    int *n_12;
    int *n_13;
    int *n_14;
    int *n_15;
    int *n_16;
    int *n_17;
} calookup_b;
```

Instead of this, which is currently used heavily in the code:

```
typedef struct calookup
{

    signed char n[box1][box2][box3][box4][box5][box6][box7][box8][memvara][memvarb][memvarc][memvard][adirect][tdirect][fs][bs][outputnum];
    double raw;
} calookup;
```

I run into trouble though, when I run into calls like this:

```
for (m = 0; m < outputnum; m++)
{
    behaviour[m] = calookup->n[s3][s4][s5][s6][wa][wb][aa][ab][a->memm[0]][a->memm[1]][a->memm[2]][a->memm[3]][a->lightdirection][a->lightsense][a->fsa][a->maxload][m];
... }
```

How do I equate the two? Should I write a function with 17+ inputs that returns the value the giant multi-dimensional array would, or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: 17 sub-arrays != a 17-dimensional array...

Comment: And a 17-dimensional array is almost certainly wrong. So you need to give more information about the data that you're trying to store/access.

Comment: Have you considered declaring 8 "boxes" and then deciding which one you are looking at?

Comment: I would be tempted to think that this 17-dimensional array would if it exists have to be very sparse. If the average size of a single dimension were only 5 you would have 355687428096000UL items already.

Comment: @user3386109 Regarding data type, it's positive or negative integer. Regarding what's trying to be stored, this is a small part of a much larger evolutionary algorithm program; the structure stores behavioral outputs.

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you please explain more? I'm not sure I grasp what you mean by boxes.

Comment: @BitTickler I came into the project with the 17-dimensional array calookup already extant. The code works fine with that, though looping through the array for input or output causes dramatic slowdown compared to the rest of the code, which is what I'm trying to circumvent.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston, by *8 "boxes"* I was referring to your box1, box2 etc.

Comment: If you can live with worse than O(1) run time, and the data structure is not 100% filled but rather qualifies as being "sparse", you could do the following: 1. Define the order of each dimension argument to a fixed order. 2. Encode a string, e.g. comma separated of the form "<d0>,...,<dn-1>" (e.g. "1,3,2,3") and 3. use that string as key in a lookup or store operation on a ``std::map<std::string,char>``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 17-dimensional array is not the same as 17 arrays. Simple case:

```
int array[3][3][3];  // This can hold 3x3x3 = 27 elements

int array1[3];
int array2[3];
int array3[3];       // Together, they can hold only 9 elements.
```

You can use:

```
int array1[3][3];
int array2[3][3];
int array3[3][3];    // Together, they can hold 27 elements.
```

Taking the analogy to the 17-dimensional array...

The array:

```
signed char n[box1][box2][box3][box4][box5][box6][box7][box8][memvara][memvarb][memvarc][memvard][adirect][tdirect][fs][bs][outputnum];
```

can be converted to:

```
signed char n1[box2][box3][box4][box5][box6][box7][box8][memvara][memvarb][memvarc][memvard][adirect][tdirect][fs][bs][outputnum];
signed char n2[box2][box3][box4][box5][box6][box7][box8][memvara][memvarb][memvarc][memvard][adirect][tdirect][fs][bs][outputnum];

...

signed char nN[box2][box3][box4][box5][box6][box7][box8][memvara][memvarb][memvarc][memvard][adirect][tdirect][fs][bs][outputnum];
```

Comment: You put it brilliantly, and just reading the first line in your first code block I saw how I'm approaching this all wrong. Thanks for the insight! Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Idea to improve run time: Since then all 3 arrays receive the same arguments for each dimension, you could instead precompute the offset (pointer arithmetic) and simply go for nN+offset instead of having the [][][] indexing multiple times... or maybe not :) Um... the 3 arrays should actually NOT have the same arguments if you reduce dimension, right?.

Comment: Thanks for the input @BitTickler ! I have an informal meeting today on this project, and I'll bring up this suggestion, and your other one above, to my coworkers as we decide what to do.

Comment: Alternate view: Were the input to the learning algorithm perfect white noise, all bins in the array should have the same value (after waiting a short infinite while). If on the other hand, the state space is supposed to show some clustering around some axis/lines/cubes,... the array would be sparsely occupied. So I think turning the 17-dimensional cube into a hash table / tree where the 17 dimensions are encoded in a string (or similar) would at least help save memory (and page faults and cache misses, swapping...) and might turn out to be faster than a brute force implementation.